# Why do I have an error on my code with my files?

Tags: python, python-3.7, turtle-graphics

So the lines of the file mystery.txt contain either the word UP or DOWN or a pair of numbers. UP and DOWN are instructions for a turtle to lift up or put down its pen. The pair of numbers are some x,y-coordinates. The first few lines of mystery.txt are

```py
UP
-218 185
DOWN
-240 189
-246 188
-248 183
```

The error is in my else statement that says:

```py
sammy.goto(wordList[i],wordList[i+1])
```

I want to know why I am not supposed to use [i+1] in this particular case and how to fix it. Below is my code...

```py
import turtle
turtle.setup(800,600) # Change the width of the drawing to 800px and the height to 600px.
wn = turtle.Screen()
sammy = turtle.Turtle()

inFile = open('mystery.txt','r')
fileString = inFile.read()   # read entire file into a string
inFile.close()   # we're done with the file, so we can close it now
wordList = fileString.split()

for i in range(len(wordList)):
    if str(wordList[i]) == "UP":
        sammy.penup()

    elif wordList[i] == "DOWN":
        sammy.pendown()

    else:
        sammy.goto(wordList[i],wordList[i+1])
        i += 1
```

The error is on line 15 of the code directly after the else statement. The error states:

```py
IndexError: list index out of range on line 15
```

Comment: @Rob Bricheno So how would I replace that then?

Comment: @Rob Bricheno i understand how a for loop could work. but what would I do inside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a cleaner way to do it.

We iterate on the lines of the file one by one, and treat each one when we read it.

When we have a line of coordinates, we split it and convert the values to int.

```
import turtle
turtle.setup(800,600) # Change the width of the drawing to 800px and the height to 600px.
wn = turtle.Screen()
sammy = turtle.Turtle()

with open('mystery.txt','r') as inFile:  # using with will take care of closing the file, whatever happens 
    for line in inFile:  # read and treat the file line by line
        line = line.strip()  # remove the trailing '\n'

        if line == "UP":
            sammy.penup()

        elif line == "DOWN":
            sammy.pendown()

        else:
            # we have a pair of coordinates, we split the line and convert the coords to int
            x, y = map(int, line.split())
            sammy.goto(x, y)
```

Note that you most of the time don't need to use indices when iterating in Python, which avoids the kind of problem you met.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the real problem here is your misunderstanding about what `i += 1` does in this code:

```
for i in range(len(wordList)):
    # ...
    else:
        # ...
        i += 1
```

Unlike a language like **C**, in a `for` loop, you can't influence the value of variable `i` for the next iteration.  If `i` would have been `4` on the next iteration, then `i += 1` at the end of this iteration won't change that.  Whatever you do to `i` in the body of the `for` loop has no effect on the next iteration.  However, we can use a `while` instead in this situation:

```
import turtle

turtle.setup(800, 600)

inFile = open('mystery.txt')
fileString = inFile.read()
inFile.close()

wordList = fileString.split()

while wordList:
    if wordList[0] == "UP":
        turtle.penup()
    elif wordList[0] == "DOWN":
        turtle.pendown()
    else:
        turtle.goto(int(wordList[0]), int(wordList[1]))
        wordList.pop(0)

    wordList.pop(0)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

Though what I would actually do would be line-by-line as @ThierryLathuille suggests:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

COMMAND_FILE = 'mystery.txt'

COMMANDS = {'UP': Turtle.penup, 'DOWN': Turtle.pendown}

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(800, 600)

turtle = Turtle()

with open(COMMAND_FILE) as inFile:
    for line in inFile:
        line = line.strip()

        if line in COMMANDS:
            COMMANDS[line](turtle)
        else:
            turtle.goto(map(int, line.split()))

screen.exitonclick()
```